# Menu Bar quit working

Tags: html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZx7i.jpg

if you take a look at the image you'll see that my menu bar is being placed in a div instead of on the main page.. to explain the reason it looks like this is because the website that I'm creating this profile on doesn't allow certain things to be done, so I have to position some of the divs -1500px and use ease-in-out to bring it to the target spot, Hope this photo helps understand the issue.

ok so I finally got everything working fine, but now my issue is with chrome.. I don't know if chrome updated something or what ? but everything is working perfect on mozilla firefox,, but not on chrome ? is there a reason for this ?

The issue is with the right_menu / Sub_menu or something.. or even the gradient ? I'm not sure why it's working fine on mozilla and not chrome.. everything use to work fine with chrome until now

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sb92hx0k/2/)

```css
#right_menu {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FF00FF, #77047e);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#FF00FF, #77047e);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FF00FF, #77047e);
  background: linear-gradient(#FF00FF, #77047e);
  display: table;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 46px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right top 0;
  width: 100vh;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#right_menu li {
  display: table-cell;
}

#right_menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sub_menu
/* same as #right_menu li ul */

{
  display: none;
  left: 18%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -46px;
}

.sub_menu li a {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#77047e, #FF00FF);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#77047e, #FF00FF);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#77047e, #FF00FF);
  background: linear-gradient(#77047e, #FF00FF);
}

#right_menu li:hover .sub_menu {
  display: block;
}

#right_menu>li a:hover {
  background: #FF00FF;
}
```

```html
<ul id="right_menu">
  <li><a href="#profile_comments">Message Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Galleries</a>
    <ul class="sub_menu">
      <li><a href="#profile_password_photo_galleries">PW Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#profile_photo_galleries">My Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#profile_interests_content">Interest</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile_about_me_friends">About Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home_page">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: it's the rotation combined with transform-origin ... -90deg from the right/top == disappear

Comment: @TemaniAfif well it brings it back out on js fiddle but doesn't show on my website.. also even on js fiddle its not positioning top right now.. any thought ?

Comment: i got everything working on jsfiddle correctly, but when i use it on the website nothing shows up.. the website has added new options to pick css framwork , which includes bootstrap 4.0 beta / foundation and bulma and a few others, the menu bar seemed to disappear after this update, I pick none in the framework selection and still has the issue..

Comment: can you show us the broken code in action?

Comment: @RozzA I included a JsFiddle in my post

Comment: @RozzA my issue is different now, everything works fine on mozilla firefox but now its not working on chrome ? i don't know if chrome updated something or what ?

Comment: if you open the jsfiddle on chrome and mozilla you will see the issue

Comment: Consider using a bootstrap framework. It will allow your website to be more responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These properties should do the trick:

```
#right_menu {

  width:100vh;
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%) rotate(-90deg);
  left: 100%;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amrnn/kadmw3t1/)

Comment: works fine on JsFiddle but not on the website im using it on

Comment: let me check something

Comment: ok , well its clickable now where its suppose to be located but still not showing.

Comment: I don't know, can't say for sure what the problem is without seeing it.

Comment: the only way i could do that is giving you access to my account and letting you log in , and i don't want to do that over public messages

Comment: if you have a local server running, you can provide a safe public url using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Comment: its not local,, but now when i put the code   transform: translate(-100%, -100%) rotate(-90deg); it shows the menu_bar but everything else on the site is jacked up

Comment: I don't know, the properties should only affect the menu, one note though: on your fiddle you're missing the closing `</ul>` for your menu, don't know if that's the case on your site too.

Comment: the site i use this on is a mess already.. i have to take certain things and position them around 1500px to the right and use ease-in-out when clicking on the menu bar and then they show visible with my target code, only way to do that.. there-for on some of the coding i have to put - to bring it left of the bar and now its showing the divs that i position -1500px on the original location where its suppose to be, i'll try adding the closing ul

Comment: the closing ul is there

Answer (score 1):

Add below CSS code in in your CSS file. This solution will only modify Chrome behavior of right menu appearance, rest will work as before.

```
/* Chrome */
@media and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  #right_menu{display:initial;} 
}

/* Chrome 29+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
  and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
    #right_menu{display:initial;} 
}

/* Chrome 22-28 */
@media screen and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
   #right_menu{display:initial;} 
}
```

Find the modified code of yours, below:-

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

img {
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: list-item;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th,
td,
caption {
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}

q {
  quotes: none;
}

q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

sub,
sup,
small {
  font-size: 75%;
}

sub,
sup {
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -.5em;
}

svg {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica;
  background: url() no-repeat center 0, #000 url() left top;
  background-size: 1670px 950px;
}

#header_bar,
#profile_header,
#profile_main_photo,
#footer_bar {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#right_menu {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FF00FF, #77047e);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#FF00FF, #77047e);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FF00FF, #77047e);
  background: linear-gradient(#FF00FF, #77047e);
  display: table;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 46px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 46px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: right top 0;
  width: 100vh;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#right_menu li {
  display: table-cell;
}

#right_menu li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sub_menu
/* same as #right_menu li ul */

{
  display: none;
  left: 18%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -46px;
}

.sub_menu li a {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#77047e, #FF00FF);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#77047e, #FF00FF);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#77047e, #FF00FF);
  background: linear-gradient(#77047e, #FF00FF);
}

#right_menu li:hover .sub_menu {
  display: block;
}

#right_menu>li a:hover {
  background: #FF00FF;
}

#home_page {
  width: 960px;
  height: 468px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 300px;
  left: 25%;
  padding: 40px;
  z-index: -999999;
  transition: left .4s ease-in-out;
}

#profile_about_me_friends .heading {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #FF00FF;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #666666;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#profile_about_me_friends {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Baskerville Old Face", serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255);
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  right: -1200px;
  padding: 40px;
  transition: left 0 ease-in-out;
}

#profile_about_me_friends_content {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Baskerville Old Face", serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#profile_about_me_friends:target {
  right: 80%;
  top: 0;
  margin-right: -520px;
}

#profile_about_me_friends .profile_section_content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 580px;
}

#profile_interests_content .heading {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #FF00FF;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #666666;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#profile_interests_content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Baskerville Old Face", serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255);
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  right: -1200px;
  padding: 40px;
  transition: left 0 ease-in-out;
}

#profile_interests_content:target {
  right: 80%;
  top: 0;
  margin-right: -520px;
}

#profile_interests_content .profile_section_content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 580px;
}

#profile_comments .heading {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #666666;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#profile_comments {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  color: #FF00FF;
  font-family: "Baskerville Old Face", serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255);
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  right: -1200px;
  padding: 40px;
  transition: left 0 ease-in-out;
}

#profile_comments:target {
  right: 80%;
  top: 0;
  margin-right: -520px;
}

#profile_comments .profile_section_content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 580px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#profile_photo_galleries .heading {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #FF00FF;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #666666;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#profile_photo_galleries {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Baskerville Old Face", serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255);
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  right: -1200px;
  padding: 40px;
  transition: left 0 ease-in-out;
}

#profile_photo_galleries:target {
  right: 80%;
  margin-right: -520px;
  top: 0;
}

.photo_gallery {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 95.7%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 99;
}

.photo_gallery .heading {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 38px;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #666666;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.photo_gallery .images a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.photo_gallery_preview {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.photo_gallery_name a {
  color: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.photo_gallery_link {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.photo_gallery_count {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #666;
}

#profile_password_photo_galleries .heading {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #FF00FF;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #666666;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#profile_password_photo_galleries {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Baskerville Old Face", serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255);
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  right: -1200px;
  padding: 40px;
  transition: left 0 ease-in-out;
}

#profile_password_photo_galleries {
  right: 300%;
  margin-right: -520px;
}

.password_photo_gallery_preview {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
}

#profile_password_photo_galleries:target {
  right: 80%;
  top: 0;
  margin-right: -520px;
}

.password_photo_gallery_name a {
  color: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.password_photo_gallery {
  position: absolute;
  top: 850px;
  right: 515px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #121212;
  padding: 40px;
  overflow: auto;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 23px;
  top: 120px;
  color: #FF00FF;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 15px;
  top: 40px;
  color: #FF00FF;
}


/* Chrome */

@media and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  #right_menu {
    display: initial;
  }
}


/* Chrome 29+ */

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
  #right_menu {
    display: initial;
  }
}


/* Chrome 22-28 */

@media screen and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  #right_menu {
    display: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="right_menu">
  <li><a href="#profile_comments">Message Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Galleries</a>
    <ul class="sub_menu">
      <li><a href="#profile_password_photo_galleries">PW Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#profile_photo_galleries">My Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#profile_interests_content">Interest</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile_about_me_friends">About Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#home_page">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: I had high hopes that this was going to work.. The menu bar is actually showing up inside the divs as i scroll down the page , the menu bar and other items show up in the location its suppose to be  only when i scroll down the page and it goes over a div but goes away if i keep scrolling.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get your requirement properly. Can you show me some working/non expected scenario? As per my understanding from your comment, the right menu is enclosed in a div and that div should be fixed in position always, regardless of scroll. In that case, you have to make the parent div as position fixed, not the UL element.

Comment: I have position absolute because I use transition ease in out and a target for the div

Comment: Im drawing a blank here. it's just showing up underneath everything it seems like, and when I scroll the page to the right where the divs are hiding from the page the menu bar shows up in the div but when I load the page up and click on the area the menu bar / nav bar is suppose to be it allows me to click and it brings the target divs to the location, i don't have any clue whats going on here. I know its something to do with the background linear gradient because when i add other stuff to that it shows the menu bar but looks totally different and in a different spot

Comment: I awarded you the bounty because you at least tried for the most part , even tho it didn’t fix my issue I still hope you continue to try and help me fix my issue because I know if I don’t award the bounty nobody gets rewarded and I don’t get the rep back , so I rather someone have it than nobody,

Comment: ,, cmon bro still need your help

Answer (score 0):

Change display property from table to block and right property to the width of your menu.

for example:

```
#right_menu{
      display: block;
      right: 46px;
}
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: Will check when I get home